sqlalchemy async запрос для mysql
как можно сделать URL на создание асинхронного движка? что нужно писать для драйвера в функции DATABASE_URL_async?
Код движка
engine = create_async_engine(
        url=settings.DATABASE_URL,
        echo=False
    )
with engine.connect() as con:
    res = con.execute(text('SELECT VERSION()'))
    print(f'{res.all()=}')

Код создания URL
from dotenv import dotenv_values



class Settings():
    DB_HOST: str
    DB_PORT: int
    DB_USER: str
    DB_PASS: str
    DB_NAME: str

    def __init__(self):
        self.DB_HOST = data.get('DB_HOST')
        self.DB_PORT = data.get('DB_PORT')
        self.DB_USER = data.get('DB_USER')
        self.DB_PASS = data.get('DB_PASS')
        self.DB_NAME = data.get('DB_NAME')

    @property
    def DATABASE_URL_asynс(self):
        return f"mysql://{self.DB_USER}:{self.DB_PASS}@{self.DB_HOST}:{self.DB_PORT}/{self.DB_NAME}"

    @property
    def DATABASE_URL(self):
        return f"mysql+pymysql://{self.DB_USER}:{self.DB_PASS}@{self.DB_HOST}:{self.DB_PORT}/{self.DB_NAME}"


data = dotenv_values()
settings = Settings()

